# Robot Class typing in the Address Bar(URL) instead of textbox when script is executed in Run Mode

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, awtrobot

I have a selenium script which has a step to type in a textbox using Robot class, I am using the below code to type into the textbox :

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_3);
```

When in Debug mode, this works fine as the window/cursor is in focus but when executed in Run mode, the Robot class types in the address bar of the browser instead of textbox. [image: Typed "333" in address bar instead of SerachBox]

Answer (score 0):

1.First click on textbox using
Driver.findElement(By.Xpath("xpath of textbox")).click(); or Driver.findElement(By.Xpath("xpath of textbox")).sendKeys("");

2. Then use your script.
   Robot robot = new Robot();
   robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_3);

Note:- scroll to that textbox using javascript if unable to click.

Comment: That also didn't work. It clicks in the textbox but still types in the address bar. I can see 2 cursors on screen at that time.

Comment: ok no issue. if possible can you share more code because how are you accessing browser. It might be sync issue. put some wait before typing in that box. at my end it is working using proper wait for visibility of that element and using sendkeys() method.